How to fix double menu error on wp elementor?
i migrated my website from one wordpress to the other , after the migration my wp website is showing double menu error , how to solve it?
I tried by uninstalling plugins one by one , updating them and regenerating css in elementor tool section but still error appears.

Elementor is one of the best website builders for WordPress, just go to menus and rearrange them according to hierarchy. It will be working fine.
